# How can I find the instance of a user in this javascript user system codebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to use this user system(https://github.com/jedireza/drywall/) for a simple chat application that I am building. I am having a hard time figuring out how to find the class/object that instantiates the current/logged-in user. I understand that the system uses express as the webserver, so Im guessing thats a good place to start to link server requests to users looking to login. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Just understanding the 'flow' of the program/system would help alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it, but it's built using Mongoose and it exposes a db.users collection which you can query for user information. If you're interested in that, you can use it like so:

```
db.users.findOne({ username: 'pinky' }, function(err, user) {
    // work with user here if it was found!
});
```

You will have access to the following user properties and functions based off of the [schema](https://github.com/jedireza/drywall/blob/master/schema/User.js):

```
  var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: String,
    email: String,
    roles: {
      admin: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Admin' },
      account: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account' }
    },
    isActive: String,
    timeCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    twitter: {},
    github: {},
    facebook: {},
    search: [String]
  });
  userSchema.methods.canPlayRoleOf = function(role) { ... };
  userSchema.methods.defaultReturnUrl = function() { ... };
  userSchema.statics.encryptPassword = function(password) { ... };
```

It is also using Passport, so if you're looking to work with the logged in user, you can access the object through req.user.